# Add pagination to a page with sections

Tags: plugins, pagination

I have on my website, on a specific page (library), several vertically arranged sections. The problem is that there are too many (they look like posts, but they aren't). (I create and edit these sections and their design using Elementor).

How could I add a pagination system and limit the minimum number of pages visible before the paginator truncates the content?

I have come across a plugin that could be an alternative to what I'm looking for, but I can't get it to apply to these sections created with Elementor. Its name is 'Ajax Load More.'

I have searched for some plugins that can accomplish this task, but I can't find one that does what I mentioned.

Comment: you'll need to ask this in an Elementor community as it requires an Elementor specific solution

Comment: What specific place should I go to?

Comment: I don't use Elementor so I don't know much about their communities popular spots, there might be Facebook groups, discords, official places mentioned on the elementor site, etc, but questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here. If your page is too big have you considered making it two pages instead?

Comment: It is like a repository, a library. It wouldn't look good if I split it into two pages, right?

Comment: that's exactly what pagination does, split it into multiple pages. If you're going to load it in via AJAX underneath as they scroll down then I don't see how it would be any different to just loading everything at once, it'd just be too big once you scroll down rather than immediatley, but now with extra code to weigh it down